# How to make the Div movable UP and DOWN using jquery Hovering

Tags: jquery

Have one requirement, Divs movable to up and down, it is working fine.
But my requirement is once hover the DIV the up and down images will be visible for a particular div, remaining should be invisible.
I tried something, here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".main").hover(function(){
         $(".up").show();
         $(".down").show();
  },function(){
           $(".up").hide();
          $(".down").hide();  
});


    $('.up').click(function() {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            parent.insertBefore(parent.prev());
        });
        $('.down').click(function() {
            var parent = $(this).parent();
            parent.insertAfter(parent.next());
        });
    });
```

Thanks in advance

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/renab7m5/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to achieve that only the child buttons of the element shows up you can do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".main").on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).children(".down").show();
        $(this).children(".up").show();
    });

    $(".main").on('mouseleave', function(){
        $(this).children(".down").hide();
        $(this).children(".up").hide();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/renab7m5/3/

but i would suggest doing it with css.

with css you can hover the element and every child of the element too.

```
.main .down,
.main .up{
    opacity:0
}

.main:hover .up,
.main:hover .down{
    opacity:1;
}
```

you can now also transition that thing to have a nice effect. just put that css style in .down or up : transition:opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
don't forget to prefix transition for the different browsers.

grettings timotheus

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery Sortable i think its better.

http://jqueryui.com/sortable/

Check this for usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery UI for this issue: [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/) or [Sorteble](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/)